# Layout difference in SVG when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I basically wanted to add an SVG element under a div once the div is added to the page(by firing a custom event using jQuery trigger). When I  tried to do this like below:

css:

```
.full-size {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

js:

```
var div = $("<div/>").css({'width': '100px', 'height': '100px'});

div.on(<customEvent>, function() {
    var svg = $("<svg/>").addClass("full-size");

    svg.appendTo(div);
});
```

the SVG size remains 0px x 0px. But when I add the SVG through d3(shown below) it gets the entire div's width and height.

js:

```
var div = $("<div/>").attr("id", "div").css({'width': '100px', 'height': '100px'});

div.on(<customEvent>, function() {
    var svg = d3.select("#div").append("svg:svg").attr("class", "full-size");
});
```

Could someone throw some light on why this happens?

Comment: It looks like in the second case you're not appending to the `div`, but an element with ID `div`.

Comment: That can't be the main problem -- if there is no "div#div" element, then d3 just won't add anything at all.  The d3 version is working as expected, the JQuery version isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that JQuery isn't properly recognizing the svg element as an svg element.  Instead, it gets added as an "HTMLUnknownElement", which will basically default to a "span".

Test case: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9jt2n/
Check the svg properties in the DOM inspector.

A quick google suggests that JQuery doesn't have any native way of telling it to create an element as something other than HTML, but as [this article](http://blag.oztechninja.com/post/25699330571/simple-svg-manipulation-with-jquery) nicely explains, you can create the element with plain Javascript, then use JQuery for the rest.

i.e., use code like:

```
var svg = $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "svg"));

svg.attr({"class":"full-size"});

svg.appendTo(div);
```

Updated example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9jt2n/2/

In contrast, d3 methods already know all the svg element names, and automatically add them within the appropriate namespace.